# How to bypass security warning when running EXE from network location?

Tags: powershell, security, scripting

I am trying to write a complex unattended install script that installs from a network directory. I'm running PS in administrator mode with bypass security.

When I run:

`Start-Process "\\192.168.5.7\MSChart.exe" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait`

I get:

[image: Security Warning]

How can I bypass this without adding the network location as a trusted server? Ideally simply using PowerShell. I've tried Unblock-File, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried using `/quiet` or `/silent` instead of `/q` ?

Comment: Off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Well if there's a method to accomplish what I want via PS then it's programming related...

Comment: @cet51 - The argument isn't the cause. I can remove it completely and get the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Do you see the identical behavior if you try to install from a command line using `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Pretty much, except the message says, "This file is from an untrusted location. Are you sure you want to run it."

Comment: Would you want someone to be able to randomly run a script from a remote computer on the computer `you` use every day?  Me neither.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns - If they were running a PowerShell script with already two forms of security authenticated, administrator mode and with `ExecutionPolicy Bypass` then I think yes, it should run without another security prompt.

Comment: 'Pretty much, except the message says, "This file is from an untrusted location. Are you sure you want to run it."' Precisely - therefore, not a programming/PowerShell question but rather more of a superuser or serverfault question.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Except I'm wanting to override it with PowerShell...

Comment: It's an OS issue, the substance of which you should ask about on superuser or serverfault. Once you find out what needs to be changed, then you can automate using PowerShell (or whatever).

Comment: I see it's an OS issue now. When I asked the question, I was thinking there's a command to prevent that. If you do `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` supposedly it bypasses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network share is not trusted by your computer, hence it warns you. You would have to add the share to the trusted zone in the systems internet settings, and allow "launching programs and unsafe files".

You cannot bypass it, but

- add the required configuration to the registry
- or copy the files locally and run it from there

using PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the warning by adding `-NoNewWindow` as in `Start-Process "\\192.168.5.7\MSChart.exe" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait -NoNewWindow`.

You should however leverage DNS for your path (e.g. `\\share.domain.com\file.exe`) and ensure the URI (`share.domain.com`) is in your system 'Trusted Sites' or 'Intranet Sites' list or you may still be blocked. Copying the file to the local system first may also fix the problem.

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92eab96d-fe1a-4119-a5bc-f171d517466a/getting-open-file-security-warning-using-startprocess?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Hey me, thanks for the reminder, but this doesn't get rid of UAC prompts.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to `Unblock-File` and accept all of the risks that come with that and then try to execute it?

I don't recommend anyone EVER run a script like this:

```
function Unblock-Dir() 
{  
  gci -Directory | % { 
    push-location $_ ; 
    gci | % { 
      Write-Host "Unblocking $_";
      Unblock-File $_ 
    } 
    Unblock-Dir ; 
    Pop-Location 
  } 
  Unblock-File -path .\* 
}
```

It's just too dangerous.